# Search a text file for a string, and then print the line (Not working as expected)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
elif controlpanel == "B":
print("Please input numberplate below")
inputting = input()
lookup = inputting
with open('numberplates.txt') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print("found at line:", myFile.readline())
```

Here, my code is supposed to look at a .txt file called 'numberplates.txt', however, it doesnt always work.

```
Numberplate: JK76FBG Speed: 493
Numberplate: UH67KCH Speed: 1063
Numberplate: AI78DHC Speed: 1063
Numberplate: AL08HCD Speed: 173
Numberplate: JH78SCD Speed: 206
Numberplate: HJ78LBC Speed: 583
```

This is the .txt file's contents.

This is what happens if I input JK76FBG

```
Please input numberplate below JK76FBG found at line: Numberplate:
UH67KCH Speed: 1063
```

However, if i input AL08HCD, I get an error.

```
Please input numberplate below
AL08HCD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file path", line 43, in <module>
    with open('numberplates.txt') as myFile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numberplates.txt'
```

It seems to either give me an error or print the line below the string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("found at line:", myFile.readline())
```

Why are you using readline() again, just print the line

```
print("found at line:", line)
```